# RHEL Need To Boot Without rc.local

Tags: boot, rhel5, rc.local

I am running RHEL 5.5. I edited my rc.local file, but I made a bad change because now when I try to boot RHEL, I get to my normal background but the login prompt does not appear now. Is there a way I can kick off the login screen manually or boot without kicking off rc.local?

I tried booting in single user mode, that didn't help either.

Just for FYI (i'm a linux newb in case you couldnt tell), i tried adding a shell script to my startup process via rc.local. As a result, I ran into this issue...

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to edit your kernel options in grub to append:

```
init=/bin/bash
```

Failing that, you could try a rescue disk to fix your rc.local.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. the init option didnt work. Hoewver the rescue did:

1.) Boot from rescue CD or install DVD >> 2.) Run sosreport (for linux 5 users) >> 3.) In doing so, creates the rc.local in the sosreport >> 4.) Edited rc.local (etc directory) >> Rebooted under normal, machine booted fine.

Answer (score 1):

At one point in the text boot process (press <kbd>Esc</kbd> if you get the graphical bootup instead) it will ask you to press <kbd>I</kbd> for interactive boot. Do so, then answer yes to every service other than local scripts.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately this didn't work, it still booted rc.local.

Comment: Then you should report it as a bug upstream, since it *should* work.